# Reasoning for the function $f(x,y)=x^{2}e^{y}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Reasoning for the function $f(x,y)=x^{2}e^{y}$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

**Explanation :**

the correct reason should be $f_{x}=2xe^{y}$ and $f_{y}=x^{2}e^{y}$ are both continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ , then $f$ is differentiable at every point on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

But my friend told me :

$f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ both exist at each point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and for all point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we have $$f_{xy}=2xe^{y}=f_{yx}$$

Hence , $f$ is differentiable  on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I confused . Is this reason valid for testing function differentiable  ? Or is there a counterexample for this ?

Comment: You are right. The result $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$ is commonly called **Schwarz's Theorem** which requires as a condition that the function $f$ have continuous second partial derivatives.

Comment: @Hikaru: But usually that theorem is only formulated in one direction: *if* $f$ is of class $C^2$, then $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$. Your argument assumes that the *only if* direction holds too. Which I don't know right off the bat, but I would guess it's false. The question here is whether the weaker conclusion $f_{xy}=f_{yx} \implies f \in C^1$ holds.

Comment: @Hikaru: I did some searching, and here's a counterexample to the converse of Schwarz's theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095484/clairauts-theorem-is-reversible. But it's differentiable, so it's not a counterexample to the original question here.

Comment: This may be just a matter of translation, but you say "the correct reason should be ...". That should be "One reason is ...". There are other ways of proving differentiability. However, until your friend can point you at a proof that $f_{xy} = f_{yx}$ proves differentiability, do not trust it.