# Is $f$ twice continuously partially differentiable?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

I have shown that a function is continuously partially differentiable.

If it holds that $$\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}}$$ forall $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ does it follow that the function is twice continuously partially differentiable?

Comment: Perhaps see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095484/clairauts-theorem-is-reversible